# Mapping numpad keys in the VI editor

Tags: unix, vi

I've tried to map the numpad keys to work (for instance the /).
What I did is: :map! / (on the numpad) /
but when I try to use it I get 'Q' and then '/' and a space afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I've found this thread while looking for the same, so just for the record answer for me was to use `<kDivide>` as a key:

`map! <kDivide> :help <kDivide><CR>`

Answer (score 2):

Whether located on the numpad or in the main keyboard area, the <kbd>/</kbd> keys are sending a plain "/" so are not distinguishable for the vi standpoint.